# Pygame set window on top without changing it's position

Tags: python, pygame

As I found in the following topic : [How to make python window run as "Always On Top"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482565/how-to-make-python-window-run-as-always-on-top)

I know how to put a window on top. But I would like to keep it at the same position. The autor says that he found a work around to find the x and y values. I would like to know how I can achieve that !

How can I get the x, y values of a pygame window ? Maybe it's a wrong way of doing.

The effect I am looking for is that the window goes on top when I trigger it with some function call.

For those who know League of legends, when a game starts, the window goes on top and remains at the same coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that seems pretty well done:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_long, byref #windows only


class RECT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ('left',    c_long),
    ('top',     c_long),
    ('right',   c_long),
    ('bottom',  c_long),
    ]
    def width(self):  return self.right  - self.left
    def height(self): return self.bottom - self.top


def onTop(window):
    SetWindowPos = windll.user32.SetWindowPos
    GetWindowRect = windll.user32.GetWindowRect
    rc = RECT()
    GetWindowRect(window, byref(rc))
    SetWindowPos(window, -1, rc.left, rc.top, 0, 0, 0x0001)
```

Now in order to put a window on top, simply call `onTop(pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window'])` to handle your pygame window.

Comment: But how to stop it?

Answer (score 5):

There's a shorter solution using the same [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
from ctypes import windll
SetWindowPos = windll.user32.SetWindowPos

NOSIZE = 1
NOMOVE = 2
TOPMOST = -1
NOT_TOPMOST = -2

def alwaysOnTop(yesOrNo):
    zorder = (NOT_TOPMOST, TOPMOST)[yesOrNo] # choose a flag according to bool
    hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window'] # handle to the window
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, zorder, 0, 0, 0, 0, NOMOVE|NOSIZE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
import win32gui
import win32con

win32gui.SetWindowPos(pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window'], win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0,0,0,0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
```

The window doesn't move because I used the `SWP_NOMOVE` tag

Answer (score 0):

Getting current window position:

```
from ctypes import POINTER, WINFUNCTYPE, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, HWND, RECT


# get our window ID:
hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]

# Jump through all the ctypes hoops:
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HWND, POINTER(RECT))
paramflags = (1, "hwnd"), (2, "lprect")

GetWindowRect = prototype(("GetWindowRect", windll.user32), paramflags)

# finally get our data!
rect = GetWindowRect(hwnd)
print "top, left, bottom, right: ", rect.top, rect.left, rect.bottom, rect.right

# bottom, top, left, right:  644 98 124 644
```

Putting the window on the foreground:

```
x = rect.left
y = rect.top
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Windows 11 system with Python 3.11.2 and for some reason, the `SetWindowPos` from `windll.user32` library does not work. However the same `SetWindowPos` function from `win32gui` library works perfectly. Just do the exact [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74275111/8760435) [@ZiyadCodes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16414566/ziyadcodes) gave earlier.

To install required libraries:

```
$ pip install win32gui
$ pip install win32con
```

To keep `pygame` window always on top:

```
import win32gui
from win32con import SetWindowPos

SetWindowPos(pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window'], win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0,0,0,0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
```